# Write a function in shell script to check if the two numbers are Palindromes

Tags: bash, function, shell, scripting, palindrome

I'm writing a function in shell script to check if the two numbers are Palindromes but I am getting an error, It is showing error in line 18 command not found. Please help me how can I remove this error.
#!/bin/bash

```
echo "Enter two number:"
read a
read b
for num in $a $b;
do
    x=$x$sep$num
    sep=" "
done
y=$x
num1=$a
num2=$b
rem=""
rev=0
for word in $y;
do
checkPalindrome $word
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "$word is palindrome"
fi
done
checkPalindrome() {
local s=$1
for i in $s ;
do
while [ $i -gt 0]
do
rem=$(($i%10));
rev=$(($rev*10+$rem));
i=$(($i / 10));
done
done

if [[ $rev -eq $num1 && $rev -eq $num2  ]]
then
return 0;
else
return 1;
fi
}
```

Comment: You need to define `checkPalindrome` *before* you use it. Note: including the full & exact error message would've made this much more obvious.

Comment: I have defined checkPalindrome below as you can see but still I'm getting error please check this.

Comment: You need to define `checkPalindrome()` **before** you use it. Currently you are definining it **after** you try to use it. Please move the definition of `checkPalindrome()` above where you try to call it.

Comment: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `checkPalindrome $word; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...`, just write `if checkPalindrome $word; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your `checkPalindrome()` definition *before* you use it, as below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

checkPalindrome() {
    local s=$1

    for i in $s
    do
        while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]
        do
            rem=$((i%10))
            rev=$((rev*10+rem))
            i=$((i / 10))
        done
    done

    if [[ $rev -eq $num1 && $rev -eq $num2 ]]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

echo "Enter two number:"
read -r a
read -r b

for num in $a $b
do
    x="$x$sep$num"
    sep=" "
done

y="$x"
num1="$a"
num2="$b"
rem=""
rev=0
for word in $y;
do
    if checkPalindrome "$word"
    then
        echo "$word is palindrome"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the input as string (you don't have to restrict it to be an integer)

```
#!/bin/bash

is_palindrome() {
    local arg=$1 i j
    for ((i = 0, j = ${#arg} - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)); do
        [[ ${arg:i:1} = "${arg:j:1}" ]] || return
    done
}

read -r -p 'Enter two words: ' a b
for word in $a $b; do
    is_palindrome "$word" && echo "$word is palindrome"
done
```